# SQL Server Replication Administrative Password not working

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have been struggling for the past one week to setup the replication in our environment and has been stuck on Administrative Password issue when adding Distributor on Publisher Server.

### Important Note: All of our SQL Server environment is on EC2 AWS Cloud instances. I hope it is not Amazon that is blocking this feature.

Replication Configuration I'm using:

- Distributor: Remote Distributor(as we do not want any performance impact on our prod)
- SQL Server Version: Is same on all servers (Distributor, Publisher, and Subscriber)
- Instance: Default instance (not named)
- No firewall in our environment.
- All servers are fully connected (Can connect to each other via SSMS).
- Remote access is enabled.

Troubleshooting I have performed:

1. Reset the Distributor password from Distributor Properties. (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/dadf963d-9246-44ed-841a-10d27a6cdc4e/not-able-to-connect-to-remote-distributor-from-publisher-using-administrative-link-password?forum=sqlreplication)
2. Removed publishers and added it back and reset the password.
3. Deleted the whole distributor and reconfigured.
4. Changed distributor_admin password from Security (GUI) and using the script method (sp_changedistributor_password [ @password = ] 'password')
5. Tried the configuration on another server as distributor.
6. Ensured password policy is met, even removed password policy enforcement.
7. Removed distributor, changed SSMS version and configured the distributor again.
8. Configured the whole setup using scripts only.
9. Checked the Error log of target Server (No login or repl related errors)
10. Searched for the issue exhaustively on forums.

No solution has worked so far, any input will be appreciated.

[image]

Additional Info:

When I configured the Distributor on remote machine it created two Linked Servers (repl_distributor and Second as servername of the publisher server). When I tested the connection of both servers I got error as below screenshot. Online search suggest enabling MSDTC which is did but no luck with resolving the original issue or even the Linked Server issue.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the step of the print on [this microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-preparing-the-server-for-replication?view=sql-server-ver15). Could you provide the link of the tutorial you're following?

Comment: When I've had issues with Replication I've found useful information in the history of the associated agent jobs. Look on the distribution server first, but it might be worth looking at them all.

Comment: No useful or almost no information on either Distributor or Publisher server logs.

Comment: Those linked servers are "special" in that they are created specifically for use by replication, and not for "normal" linked server use.  It's not clear what your **ACTUAL** problem is. Is your replication broken? This seems like the middle part of your troubleshooting, without identifying the original problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @AMtwo As mentioned in the beginning of question I'm trynig to configure replication in our environment and when doing so I'm stuck at the the Administrative Password step as in the screenshot . Disregard the Linked Servers I have mentioned at the bottom in my comment.

Comment: @Ali Were you ever able to figure this out?